# Android Constraint Layout : Centering views between 2 guidelines

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am dividing my screen up into 4 columns which are 25% the width of the screen, I then place a TextView between guideline 1 and 2 for example. The issue is, they do not seem to be centering between the guidelines.

I have tried LeftOf, StartOf, EndOf, gravity and TextAlign.  Its been a while since I did Constraints

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeInternetLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/home_internet_label"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeInternetStatus"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeInternetLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_internet_status" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      android:text="@string/home_server_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerStatus"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_server_status" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
      android:text="@string/home_last_sync_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncDateTime"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_last_sync_value" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeViewLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      android:text="@string/home_view_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeViewValue"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeViewLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_view_value" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2 **

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeInternetLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/home_internet_label"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeInternetStatus"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeInternetLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_internet_status" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      android:text="@string/home_server_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerStatus"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_server_status" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
      android:text="@string/home_last_sync_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncDateTime"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeLastSyncLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_last_sync_value" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeViewLabel"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      android:text="@string/home_view_label" />

  <uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewHomeViewValue"
      style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHomeViewLabel"
      android:text="@string/home_view_value" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: *The issue is, they do not seem to be centering between the guidelines.* - but what **are** they doing?

Comment: You can use chains without the need for guidelines, and set gravity to center.

Comment: Add some pictures, it's hard to see what the problem is

Comment: You don't need the 0 and 1 guidelines. I assume the problem is that you changed e.g. `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` to `_toRightOf="parent"`, which is a major functional change. For guidelines it doesn't matter whether you use `_toLeftOf` or `_toRightOf`, because guidelines have infinitely small width. For other views that have non-zero width, and especially for `parent`, it matters very much which one you use.

Comment: Added picture to show problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just ran your code up and it does seem to be that you're missing the gravity attribute (`android:gravity="center"`). Your guidelines seem fine as everythings split into 25% sections.

If gravity isn't working, check out your style to see if it's definitely being set, you could be adding app: instead of android: or vice versa. Try adding gravity to the `TextView` in the XML and removing the style and then work from there.

Comment: Thank you, I did try it however the textbox below is not centered but the top one is?

Comment: and you've added the gravity attribute to each TextView?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, guideline1 comes before guideline2, so taking in example this portion of layout:

```
<uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
  style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
  android:text="@string/home_server_label" />
```

should be:

```
<uk.co.reach.gc.widget.CustomFontTextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHomeServerLabel"
  style="@style/Theme.Reach.HomeStatusPhone.Label"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
  android:text="@string/home_server_label" />
```

In conclusion, your constraintLeft and constraintRight are wrong. Try making these changes also for other views.

Comment: this doesn't really matter, at worst it would make the textview overlap with the guideline

Comment: I did try this and sadly made little difference but thanks

Comment: This answer is harmless, but the concept behind the content is incorrect. Guidelines have zero width, so their "left" and "right" are identical. You can test this very easily by positioning two views with translucent backgrounds against the same guideline; you will not see any pixels with overlapping backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem will go away if you add this attribute to your TextViews:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Alternatively, you could change your width to:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

As things are right now, you are combining `android:layout_width="0dp"` with left+right constraints. This will make the view stretch to be exactly as wide as the space between those two guidelines... but TextView left-justifies its text by default if the text length is shorter than the view width.